# Presenting modal view controller in Table View

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

Good day, everyone.

I have this code in table view controller:

```
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {


        if([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)
        {
            citySearch = [[CitySearch alloc] initWithNibName:@"CitySearchIphone5" bundle:nil];

        }
        else
        {
            citySearch = [[CitySearch alloc] initWithNibName:@"CitySearch" bundle:nil];
        }
        UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:citySearch];
        [self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

so, when it is presented i see view, that is going over bounds and Xcode write this

> Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged

how to solve it?

Comment: Are you using your table view in a UISplitViewController? I got the same message when using the master view of a split view to present the modal view controller. Using the split view to present it solved this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`presentModalViewController:animated:` is deprecated in `iOS 6.0`. Use `presentViewController:animated:completion:` instead.

```
[self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#jumpTo_8)

Comment: i did so. nothing changed (

Comment: Are you using Storyboards? Check if the `navController` or `citySearch` is having a `segue` back to your table view controller ?

Comment: i don't have Storyboards

Comment: Then check if a `rootViewController` is set in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` ?

Comment: i did forget to add the CitySearch controller to rootController. It works now, but there is some strange space on the top of the presented view - what is this?

Comment: That is because you are presenting a new `UINavigationController` which by default contains a `UINavigationBar` at the top.

Comment: thank you i managed to remove the space :) but there is one more problem. The presented view is TableView and its left bound is invisible

Comment: i solved it. but there is another: when i dismiss modal view, parent view is going left and up

Answer (score -1):

```
 MACommentsViewController *obj_AboutVC;
 if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
 {
    if (IS_IPHONE_5)
    {
        obj_AboutVC = [[MACommentsViewController alloc]         initWithNibName:@"MACommentsViewController" bundle:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        obj_AboutVC = [[MACommentsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MACommentsViewController_iPhone4" bundle:nil];
    }
}

[self presentViewController:obj_AboutVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```